# Using Twilio with Meteor to respond to SMS

Tags: node.js, meteor, twilio

I have recently started learning how to use node.js and Meteor. I am trying to create a small app that I can query via a client built in meteor, but also query that same MongoDB via SMS using the Twilio API. I can see that this can be done with Express: [How can I respond to incoming Twilio calls and SMS messages using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556426/how-can-i-respond-to-incoming-twilio-calls-and-sms-messages-using-node-js) but I wanted to use Meteor because of its apparent ease-of-use and  integration with a database. I've been reading various questions about routing templates and serving static html pages in Meteor, but is there a solid way someone think I can make this work? Should I just go back to plain Express?

Twilio expects you to give them the URL where the XML response will be hosted: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My earlier response is outdated. Today one should use [iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) and create a server-side route.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I found it easier to rewrite my application using express and redis, using express to route the Twilio sms response URL

Comment: could you upload some example code for this?  I'm struggling with the same issue, and it would really help