# Twilio SMS reply in node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm writing a mobile notification system using twilio in node.js and I am currently able to send SMS messages to users. But I would like users to reply back with a response.  I would need to gather the phone number the user sent the text from as well as the contents of the message (to query my mongoosedb)

I couldn't find much info on this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio evangelist here.

Check out [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html) which introduces you to our Node helper.  If you scroll down to the section titled "*Generating TwiML to handle inbound calls and SMS*", it will walk you through receiving an SMS message from Twilio.

The basic idea is that when your user replies to your message, Twilio is going to tell you that by making an HTTP request to some URL that you have configured for your Twilio phone number.  That URL is some endpoint that you have created in your Node app.

As part of that request, Twilio is going to pass some form parameters to you.  In your going to use the request object that is passed into the POST function to get the parameters that Twilio passes you:

```
console.log(request.body.from);
console.log(request.body.to);
```

Heave over to [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) on our website to see all of the parameters Twilio will send you when we

Hope that helps.

Comment: For some reason POST isn't working with Heroku TwiML. GET works though. Should I be able to retrieve the SMS parameters using a GET request instead of POST in node.js? I'm trying to get the parameters in my javascript without using TWiML.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556426/how-can-i-respond-to-incoming-twilio-calls-and-sms-messages-using-node-js