# Handling inbound Twilio messages using node.js

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

I'm reading through portions of the Twilio documentation (https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/why-does-my-twilio-number-respond-with-thanks-for-the-message-configure-your-numbers-sms-url-to-change-this-message) pertinent to SMS messaging responses, and am trying to build a node.js app which will allow me to respond to inbound SMS messages with programmatic responses.

I've been trying to emulate this SO post which deals with a similar problem ([How can I respond to incoming Twilio calls and SMS messages using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556426/how-can-i-respond-to-incoming-twilio-calls-and-sms-messages-using-node-js)) and have the following code:

```
var AUTH_TOKEN = "*********************";
var twilio = require('twilio');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());


app.post('/welcome/sms/reply/', function(req, res) {
    //Validate that this request really came from Twilio...
    if (twilio.validateExpressRequest(req, AUTH_TOKEN)) {
        var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
        twiml.say('Hi!  Thanks for checking out my app!');
        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());
    }
    else {
        res.send('you are not twilio.  Buzz off.');
    }
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Calling the POST request /welcome/sms/reply through a REST client yields the else statement, and I'm not sure why since the AUTH_TOKEN is exactly what I have in my account dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're trying to call your own endpoint there using a REST client and you are validating requests (`twilio.validateExpressRequest`) then you will need to construct your request the [same as Twilio does](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests). Crucially this includes a `X-Twilio-Signature` header, read more at that link for more details.

If you test your code with Twilio, it should work and be a valid request.

Comment: Thanks Phil - it turns out I wasn't setting up ngrok and changing the request URL properly in my Twilio account, so once I fixed that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

See this post for reference in incorporating ngrok + Express. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/monitoring-call-progress-events-with-node-js-and-express.html